# react-native-settings-list showing up empty

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use [react-native-settings-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-settings-list). So I used part of the code over there and tried to create two items for my settings list. However they look empty on my app? Why?

[image: simulator]

Here's my render for the class containing that screen:

```
      <View style={{backgroundColor:'white',flex:1}}>
      <View style={{flex:1, marginTop:50}}>
        <SettingsList>
          <SettingsList.Item
            icon={
              <View style={{height:90,marginLeft:10,alignSelf:'center'}}>
                <Image style={{alignSelf:'center',height:40, width:40}} source={require('../../../assets/itba-inst.png')}/>
              </View>
            }
            itemWidth={50}
            hasNavArrow={true}
            title='Icon Example'
            onPress={() => Alert.alert('Icon Example Pressed')}
          />
          <SettingsList.Item
            title='Cerrar sesión'
            backgroundColor='#D1D1D1'
            titleStyle={{color:'blue'}}
            arrowStyle={{tintColor:'blue'}}
            onPress={() => Alert.alert('Logged out')}/>
        </SettingsList>
      </View>
    </View>
```

The only weird thing I notice is at the top of my class when I wrote:

```
import SettingsList from 'react-native-setting-list';
```

I get a warning from VisualStudioCode saying:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-setting-list'. '/Users/myuser/Documents/ponte_bitbucket/node_modules/react-native-setting-list/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/react-native-setting-list` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-setting-list';`

Comment: It appears that you're using typescript in your project. What does your `tsconfig.json` file look like?

Comment: @itsanewabstract Which one? There are apparently many tsconfig.json inside many of the folders of node_modules

Comment: Is there one at the root of your project, not the ones inside of the `node_modules` folders?

Comment: @itsanewabstract No, I just checked, I don´t have one at the root.

Comment: Try following the advice of the error message and run `npm install @types/react-native-setting-list`. If that doesn't fix it then create a github repo with your full app and I'll take a look at debugging more thoroughly